# MVC extension method error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, extension-methods

Hi i've got an extension method in my PagingHelpers class:

```
 namespace SportsStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
    public static class PagingHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
                                               PagingInfo pagingInfo,
                                               Func<int, string> pageUrl)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i < pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
                if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                result.Append(tag.ToString());
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

here i call extension method in the List.cshtml:

@`Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x}))`

And I got this error:

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   does not contain a definition for 'PageLinks' and no extension method
>   'PageLinks' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I added the namespace in the web.config inside the Views Folder:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
    <add namespace="SportsStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers"/>**
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Please help me, I don't know how could I solve this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding

```
@using SportsStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers;
```

to the top of your .cshtml file

your namespace approach should work as well, so try to shut down the server rebuild your solution and run again

Comment: no problem, your namespace approach should work as well, so try to shot down the server rebuild your solution and run again, maybe it will work without the @using statement

Comment: Adding the namespace to the views/web.config should indeed be enough. I suspect the project was not recompiled prior to trying to use the html helper extension.

Comment: I followed the instructions, but it doesn't work without the @using statement

Answer (score 3):

It appears you have added the namespace reference to the root web.config file.

If you are using MVC3 with the Razor view engine, you have to add the namespace reference to the Views\web.config file. Then it will be globally available to all views within the View folder.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="SportsStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers"/>
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Don't know why this isn't marked as the answer, it's the correct way for the exercise this question is referring to.  Just helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did everything correctly.
Did you compile your web project before trying to use the Html helper?

Comment: I added it to the solution for future reference, I believe it should work, but not restarting the server is probably the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your List.cshtml above the code this line

```
@model SportsStore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel
```